# Express not render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I got a express program with use jade templates.

I have this code in `app.js`:

```
app.get('/visualizar',function(req, res) {
   res.render("visualizar");
}
```

I have configured correctly the middlewares in the folder views.

Then, I got a page in jade that have a td and a script that make a $get to visualizar if you click in the tr

```
$(window).load(function (){
     $('tr').click(() => { 
         $.get("/visualizar");
     });
});
```

The program do the get to visualizar but not render the page, why?

```
[![Gets correctly][1]][1]
```

You can view the full code in [c9](https://ide.c9.io/alu0100786330/usa)
In the archive app.js and csv.js(in the public folder this one, at the end)

Answer (score 0):

`$.get("/visualizar");` is a ajax, you need handle the result and update the UI by yourself.

or use `location.href = '/visualizar'`

Comment: what do you see when you access /visualizar in your browser @eric-ramos